# @Generated in HSQL DB

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

Assume that in a database table there is a non-key column called RECORD_ID which is auto-generated/sequenced in database.

Now in my entity for the table above, just above the field for RECORD_ID, I use the hibernate annotation @Generated to indicate to hibernate that DB will take responsibility for inserting value into that particular field. It looks like the following:

```
@Column(name = "RECORD_ID", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable =  false)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private Long recordId;
```

I run my code and it works fine. DB is inserting value as expected.

Now, I write a unit-test case with HSQL to ensure my logic is intact.
The logic has a query which fetches the record based on RECORD_ID.

Now when i create fixture and invoke my test, HSQL will not generate value for the record's RECORD_ID when I save my fixture. It leaves it as null. But the logic that I intend to test is based on fetching by RECORD_ID which isn't possible here.

It just remains null in HSQL DB. And hence I am not able to complete unit testing!

Kindly throw some light on solving this issue or any workaround.

Please find the unit-test code below

```
@Test
public void testProductCancelDAL() {
    savePrerequisites();
    Logic myLogic = new Logic();
    /* Logic fetches the reservation record based on RECORD_ID */
    assertNotNull(myLogic.invoke());

}
public void savePrerequisites() {
    //Stroing product type
    Product product = ProductFixture.createProduct();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(product);

    //Storing Itinerary
    Itinerary itn = ItnFixture.create();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(itn);

    Reservation res = ReservationFixture.create();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(res);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

Comment: You're saying that the production code works as expected, but that similar code in a unit test doesn't, is that right? If so, then show us the unit test code.

Comment: What is the definition of your column in HSQLDB? Can you post a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @JB Nizet that's right JB..Will post the unit test code too

Comment: @JB Nizet Please find my unit test code above

Comment: Can you see thatthe RECORD_ID is indeed null in database? Can you see a subsequence select query generated by Hibernate to read the generated RECORD_ID from the database after the insert? Are you sure your test database has the trigger which actually generated the RECORD_ID?

Comment: @JB Nizet My test database, is an inmemory hypersonic database. It will not have trigger and that's why it is null. I can understand that..And i need a workaround for the same to have my test running.

Comment: Please use a `file:` database instead so that you can report the `CREATE TABLE` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you said in the comments, it appears that you're testing some code which depends on a trigger in the database generating the RECORD_ID, but that you test this on an in-memory database where this trigger doesn't exist. This, obviously, won't work. You need to create the same trigger as in your production database. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/triggers-chapt.html to create triggers in a HSQLDB database.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, isn't RECORD_ID the primary key?

In such case, you should use @GeneratedValue with @Id annotation.

The problem with database-generated values is that record must be re-read after insert (it does not apply to AUTOINCREMENT columns, where last generated id can be read by dedicated instruction).

Comment: but RECORD_ID here isn't primary key